# Combinatorial optimization: split features into several subsets to maximize overall score

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, optimization

I tried to reformulate my original problem (that is quite difficult to explain) to a simpler one. Please, take it into account when you may think that the final goal doesn't make too much sense.

Problem: given a set of features f1...fn that could be correlated (even duplicated) or uncorrelated, so no any restrictions on them. We can take a subset of these features e.g. f1 and f3 and measure some objective function J(f1,f3). The goal is to split all features in K  groups so that the total objective function (sum of J per group) is maximized, i.e. J = J1 + J2 + J3 + ... + Jk.

We could do this using exhaustive search but it is too many combinations, and for large numbers  of n is intractable.

Is there any combinatorial optimization algorithm that could solve this task?

Comment: If you know nothing about the function `J` then there is no hope to solve this exactly short of exhaustive search. However if `J` has some nice structure there may be efficient approaches. Could you please share the form of your function `J`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Honestly, I need to think on the properties of J since it is not obvious. What kind of properties could it be? And where can I read in general about such approach that employ these properties? May be it will be easier then for me to formulate this properties.

Comment: A commonly considered property when optimizing over subsets would be [submodularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function).

Comment: Yes, it looks like submodular function

Comment: Probably that won't help much, but I think you should look at something such: game theory, coaltition formation and Shapley value. I suppose you're trying to solve the reverse problem to mine [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201601/coalitional-effect-in-logistic-regression-and-assessing-explanarory-variable-con] You're trying to create best coalitions, whereas I'm trying to assess the contribution that each player brings to coalition.

Comment: Yes, looks similar. Thanks for the tips, I will have a look.